# c#, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word - Discrepancy between indexes in document object content and actual positions in the document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am creating and formatting word documents using C# and "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word". After creation, I need to be able to select certain lines of the text, so I can make them appear as hyperlinks (using rng.Hyperlinks.Add). I have an ArrayList populated with start and ending indices of the string I'm interested in, but when I try to use those locations to create a Range, it works for the first instance but incorrectly selects a string of text too early in the doc for all the rest.

**What could be causing the discrepancy between the location of a given string in my document.Content.Text vs the location in the document?** Is it possible to adjust my index values to compensate for this difference or get more correct index values using a different call? (currently I create a section in the document by adding to document.Content.Text a few times, then record document.Content.Text.Length in my indices array)

An excerpt of the document ends up looking something like this, but I changed to dummy data and didn't keep the exact lengths and positions - it's just included for the visual:
[image]

Code is roughly this:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);

    int startLocation = 0;
    ArrayList startingPositions = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList endingPositions = new ArrayList();

    //loop that writes to the doc, each iteration create four line sections based 
    //on data i have in datastructure
    for (int i = 0; dataStructure.Length; i++)
    {
        startingPositions.Add(startLocation);
        document.Content.Text += dataStructure.lineOne;
        endingPositions.Add(document.Content.Text.Length);

        document.Content.Text += dataStructure.otherlineTwo;
        document.Content.Text += dataStructure.otherlineThree;
        document.Content.Text += dataStructure.otherlineFour + "\n";

        startLocation = document.Content.Text.Length;
    }

    //loop that adds hyperlinks using indexes recorded above
    for (int x = 0; x < startingPositions.Count; x++)
    {
        Range rng = document.Range(startingPositions[x], endingPositions[x]);
        rng.Select();

        rng.Hyperlinks.Add(rng, urls[x], ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The arrays in MS Office are starting from 1 not from 0.

Comment: My main problem is larger than an off by one, look at my example image in the question

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dcc13f29-d28b-4382-afc2-135011186a16/adding-hyperlinks-to-word-documents-paragraph-using-foreach-loop-interopword-assembly?forum=worddev

So there is an issue where creating the hyperlink messes up indexes like I described, but you can work around it in this case by looping backwards when creating the hyperlinks so indexing isn't affected for the location.

So my last loop becomes this:

```
    //looping backwards using x-- now
    for (int x = startingPositions.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        Range rng = document.Range(startingPositions[x], endingPositions[x]);
        rng.Select();

        rng.Hyperlinks.Add(rng, urls[x], ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
```